# How to allow an url with authentication?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am sending an url to an email by buton click. When the email user is clicking the url he want to face login cardinals. I need to do the job without login cardinals.

```
    Public Function SendMail(ByVal RuequestByEmpId As String, ByVal RuequestToEmpName As String, ByVal RuequestToEmpEmail As String) As Integer

    Dim credential As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("joycseuiu@gmail.com", "something")
    Dim msg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    Dim msgSubject As String = String.Empty
    Dim strHeading As String = String.Empty

    Dim EmployeeID As String = String.Empty
    Dim Name As String = String.Empty
    Dim Designation As String = String.Empty
    Dim Email As String = String.Empty
    Dim Department As String = String.Empty
    Dim LeaveTYpe As String = String.Empty
    Dim Reason As String = String.Empty
    Dim LeaveAppID As String = String.Empty
    Dim LeaveTo As String = String.Empty
    Dim LeaveFrom As String = String.Empty
    Dim Status As String = String.Empty




    Dim i As Integer = 0

    dsEmployeeInfoWithLeaveManagement.SelectParameters("EmployeeID").DefaultValue = RuequestByEmpId
    dsEmployeeInfoWithLeaveManagement.DataBind()
    dataview = dsEmployeeInfoWithLeaveManagement.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    Try
        EmployeeID = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("EmployeeID").ToString()
        Name = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("Name").ToString()
        Designation = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("Designation").ToString()
        Department = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("Department").ToString()
        Email = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("Email").ToString()
        LeaveTYpe = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("LeaveTYpe").ToString()
        Reason = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("Reason").ToString()
        LeaveAppID = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("LeaveAppID").ToString()
        LeaveTo = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("LeaveTo").ToString()
        LeaveFrom = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("LeaveFrom").ToString()
        Status = dataview.Item(0).Row.Item("Status").ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Dim SenderEmpName As String = "Joy Acharya"
    Dim SenderEmpEmail As String = "joycseuiu@gmail.com"



    msg.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Email, Name)
    msg.[To].Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(RuequestToEmpEmail, RuequestToEmpName))

    Dim appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

    Dim result As String = appSettings("mailSender")


    Dim strBody As New StringBuilder()

    strBody.Append("<div>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<table>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<td>")


    msg.Subject = "Leave Application Approve"
    strBody.Append("A request for leave has been submitted for your approval.")
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Request By:</span>")
    strBody.Append(Name)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>ID:</span>")
    strBody.Append(EmployeeID)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Designation:</span>")
    strBody.Append(Designation)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Department:</span>")
    strBody.Append(Department)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Leave Type:</span>")
    strBody.Append(LeaveTYpe)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Purpose:</span>")
    strBody.Append(Reason)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Leave To:</span>")
    strBody.Append(LeaveTo)
    strBody.Append("</td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<tr>" & vbCr & vbLf & " <td>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<span>Leave From:</span>")
    strBody.Append(LeaveFrom)
    strBody.Append("</td></tr>")
    strBody.Append("</table>")
    strBody.Append("<br />")
    strBody.Append("<table>")
    strBody.Append("<tr>")
    strBody.Append("<td>")
    strBody.Append("<a href='http://localhost:56945/DOZECRMPortal080716/LeaveApplication.aspx?name=Atilla&lastName=Ozgur'" + "> " + "<b>Approve</b>" + "</a>")
    strBody.Append("</td>")
    strBody.Append("<td>")
    strBody.Append("<a href='http://www.w3schools.com'" + "> " + "<b>Reject</b>" + "</a>")
    strBody.Append("</td>")
    strBody.Append("</tr>")
    strBody.Append("<table>")

    strBody.Append("</div>" & vbCr & vbLf & "            <div>" & vbCr & vbLf & "            Thank you" & vbCr & vbLf & "            <br />")
    strBody.Append("=======================================================================================")
    strBody.Append("</div>")

    msg.Body = strBody.ToString()
    msg.IsBodyHtml = True
    msg.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
    msg.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High

    Dim c As New SmtpClient()
    '----------------------------------
    'Create the SMTP Client
    c.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    c.Credentials = credential

    c.Port = 587
    c.EnableSsl = True



    Try

        c.Send(msg)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return i
End Function
```

When the email user clicking the Approve link, he has to face the
login cardinals.

I want that, email user will just click the link and he/she will be enable
to redirect the page.

How could i do that.

And thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is full of code, but the mail creation is not actually that interesting for the question. Maybe you can generate a random token when you create the mail message and save it to a database, create a page that doesn't require authentication but requires the token value as get or post parameter, check the database for the token and determine further actions.

Comment: If you want some ideas on token generation and redirection you can use the basics from this post to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/a/40261173/223742