# open webpage from within a desktop application with arguments as username and password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a developed an asp.net web application which a user can access and login to by providing a username password. Now I have to develop a Windows Form Application in which the user can also login to using the same credentials as my web application. By clicking a button in the application, I want it to open the browser and navigate the user to the web application and automatically login to my web application with same credentials. But my problem is how do I pass the credentials to my web app?

I am using Process.Start("http://localhost:8080/myAppLogin.aspx") to open up the browser and load my login page. I can pass the credentials in query string with encrypted format but that doesn't sound like a safe method of doing it. I want to pass the credentials to my webpage with some more secure method.

Any suggestions?

**This question was incorrectly edited and lost some meaningful information in it. I have re edit the question below**

**Edit**

I have a developed an asp.net web application which a user can access and login to by providing a username password. Now I have to develop a Windows Form Application.The Win Form application contains the user's Web App Credentials in a File.There's a button in my Win Form App and I want the user to login into my web app by click onto this button e.g By clicking a button in the Win Form application, I want it to open the browser and navigate the user to the web application and automatically login to my web application. But my problem is how do I pass the credentials to my web app?

I am using `Process.Start("http://localhost:8080/myAppLogin.aspx")`  to open up the browser and load my login page. I can pass the credentials in query string with encrypted format but that doesn't sound like a safe method of doing it. I want to pass the credentials to my webpage with some more secure method.

Any suggestions?

Note: **My Win Form Application can't access my Web App Database**.

Comment: Yes, definitely never send the credentials via the query string. A very insecure approach. Is this application going to be used in an enterprise environment with a Windows Domain? If so have you looked into using Windows Authentication?

Comment: How about passing the authentication token from you win forms? Let your winform call the login service and do the login for you then if successful open the web application and do the checking if user is login by checking if there is a token or passing a parameter.

Comment: @bogzy can you please provide me any link to study or the method to perform the steps you described ?

Comment: @umer apologies but currently I dont have any link to provide for reference. But you can start with:

1. Are you using restful service for your login?
2. If, yes try making a ajax POST call from your winform.
3. This might be more complex but try looking on the idea of Facebook login API.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: Assuming you want to roll your own**

OK, so I am assuming here that both WinForms application and ASP.NET application have access to the same DB as you mention that you can log in from either.

So that being the case create yourself a table AuthTokens with the following fields:

AuthToken
UserName

Create a pre-shared key that is known to both the WinForms and ASP.NET application.

In the Winforms app authenticate the user as usual. Upon successful authentication:

1. Encrypt the username with the shared key ==> userEncrypted
2. Create an MD5 hash of userEncrypted ==> authToken

Add record to AuthTokens table:

INSERT INTO AuthTokens (AuthToken, UserName) VALUES (authToken, userEncrypted)

Then call POST "http://localhost:8080/autoLogin with the authToken as part of the headers or body (your choice) and use the [PostRedirectGet pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to send the request to your WebForms application.

In the WebForms application you then:

1. Retrieve the authToken from the POST
2. Find the authToken in the AuthTokens table
3. Decrypt the UserName field from the table using the shared key ==> unencryptedUserName
4. Use the unencryptedUserName to log the user in
5. Upon success/failure do a redirect to the GET page of your choice. Take into account ALL conditions - token not found, MD5 of decrypted user does not match authToken etc. etc

Notes:

- Doing a POST means no query strings and passing stuff "easily visible". It will still be visible to someone sniffing your traffic
- At no point do you ever store anything unencrypted - EVER
- At no point do you ever send anything over the wire that is REVERSIBLE - EVER
- You only send an MD5 hash as this is not reversible
- You still need a shared secret key (PSK) which is a pain. You could store this in the DB if that was secure

Whatever you do make sure you are careful as you implement things as it is easy to get this wrong.

Extensions:

- You could look at public/private key encryption which would avoid the PSK
- Your communication should be HTTPS and not HTTP
- You could get clever with the expiry of the auth tokens - One time use, time expiry etc. etc.

**Solution 2 - Use [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) it was designed for exactly the scenario you describing.**

**Solution 2.1 - Implement your own authentication service**

For example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3, but there are others.

**Solution 3 - Find a SaaS solution that will do single sign on and user management for you**

Google will be your friend here as I cannot recommend any without violating SO policies.

Comment: Thank you very much , Actually my specs are a  little different and i mentioned in my question that both apps have different DB and don't have the access to each other's DB , The Form application just have the credentials (in XML file) of the user to login into the Web Application. But  "Adrian" edited my question incorrectly and i approved it incorrectly , apology for that . but i got the idea from your answer and make a solution according to my scenario. I have edited my question and post an answer to the problem . please see if this approach is good enough or i could do something better

Answer (score 0):

TheEdge solution works for me.I implemented the solution in my scenario as follows

**Step1** I added two columns in the Users table of  my Web App Database, (i) AuthToken (ii) AuthDateTime.

**Step2:** I host a web service in my web application which can accept and return a string

**Step3:** My Windows Form application encrypts the Username Password strings into a string and sends to the web service hosted in my Web App.

**Step4:** My web service receives the string and dcrypts it into UserName and Password strings and validates the user.

**Step5:** On successful validation i create a hashcode value (Auth Token) and a current DateTime object  and insert it into user's Table against that user. and return this AuthToken HashCode to my Windows Form Application.

**Step6:** My Form Application receives the AuthToken back and send this Token+UserName into a query string to my Web Application.

**Step7:** My Web Application receives the Username and Token in a query string and validates the username against the token value and within a range of Auth Datetime , upon successful validation it let's user login to the app , and updates the user table by setting the AuthToken and AuthDateTime values to be null against that user.

Comment: couple of issues.... S3 Potential weakness as you are sending a clear text password only protected by encryption. S6 you are sending the username in the clear.